# Spread List of Lists to Sparks DF with PySpark?

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm currently struggling with following issue:

Let's take following List of Lists:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

How can I create following Sparks DF out of it with one row per element of each sublist:

```
| min_value | value |
---------------------
|          1|      1|
|          1|      2|
|          1|      3|
|          4|      4|
|          4|      5|
|          6|      6|
|          6|      7|
```

The only way I'm getting this done is by processing this list to another list with for-loops, which basically then already represents all rows of my DF, which is probably not the best way to solve this.

THX & BR
IntoNumbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dataframe and use explode and array_min to get the desired output:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[l]], 
    ['col']
).select(
    F.explode('col').alias('value')
).withColumn(
    'min_value', 
    F.array_min('value')
).withColumn(
    'value', 
    F.explode('value')
)

df.show()
+-----+---------+
|value|min_value|
+-----+---------+
|    1|        1|
|    2|        1|
|    3|        1|
|    4|        4|
|    5|        4|
|    6|        6|
|    7|        6|
+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
data=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Extract first element in each list in data

```
j=[item[0] for item in data]
```

Zip first element to data, create df and explode column b

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(zip(j,data), ['min_value','value']).withColumn('value', F.explode(col('value'))).show()



+---------+-----+
|min_value|value|
+---------+-----+
|        1|    1|
|        1|    2|
|        1|    3|
|        4|    4|
|        4|    5|
|        6|    6|
|        6|    7|
+---------+-----+
```

Comment: You're still using a for loop which the OP said he was looking to avoid. Also, you're using the first element of the sub-list as 'min_value'. I understand this isn't explicitly stated in the question though.

Comment: @ Rahul P for the `min-value` it is attention to detail. I do not solve the problem using for loop. All that for loop is used for is to get the first element  in each list within a list comprehension statement.

Comment: I'm not trying to be negative. At least I hope not. Just stating the downsides with this line `j=[item[0] for item in data]` . The OP said `The only way I'm getting this done is by processing this list to another list with for-loops,`

Comment: @ Rahul P appreciate your feedback. Just curious, why don't you leave for OP to decide.?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Spark like solution to this:

**Basic Imports and SparkSession creation for example purposes**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local") \
        .appName("Stackoverflow problem 1") \
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Creating an arbitrary list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,3,5], [1053,23], [1,3], [5,2,15,23,5,3]]
```

Solution below:

```
# Create an rdd from the list of lists
rdd_ll = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list_of_lists)

# Compute the min from the previous rdd and store in another rdd
rdd_min = rdd_ll.map(lambda x: min(x))

# create a dataframe by zipping the two rdds and using the explode function
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd_min.zip(rdd_ll)) \
            .withColumn('value', F.explode('_2')) \
            .drop('_2') \
            .withColumnRenamed('_1', 'min_value')
```

**Output**

```
df.show()

+---------+-----+
|min_value|value|
+---------+-----+
|        1|    1|
|        1|    3|
|        1|    5|
|       23| 1053|
|       23|   23|
|        1|    1|
|        1|    3|
|        2|    5|
|        2|    2|
|        2|   15|
|        2|   23|
|        2|    5|
|        2|    3|
+---------+-----+
```